# Prevent x axis labels from moving to the top of plot when y axis is reversed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently updated some packages and I think it changed the behavior of some code I have been using to create 96 well plate layouts.

This is the code:

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x=Column, y=Row)) +
  geom_point(data=expand.grid(seq(1, 12), seq(1,8)), 
             aes(x=Var1, y=Var2),
             color="grey90", 
             fill="white", 
             shape=21, 
             size=12) +
  coord_fixed(ratio=(13/12)/(9/8), 
              xlim=c(0.5, 12.5), 
              ylim=c(0.5, 8.5)) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks=seq(1, 8),
                  labels=LETTERS[1:8]) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 12))
```

[image: Figure 1]

If I don't reverse the y axis, I don't have any issues with the x axis:

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x=Column, y=Row)) +
  geom_point(data=expand.grid(seq(1, 12), seq(1,8)), 
             aes(x=Var1, y=Var2),
             color="grey90", 
             fill="white", 
             shape=21, 
             size=12) +
  coord_fixed(ratio=(13/12)/(9/8), 
              xlim=c(0.5, 12.5), 
              ylim=c(0.5, 8.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 8),
                  labels=LETTERS[1:8]) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 12))
```

[image: Figure 2]

Looking for a way to generate a plot with the y axis reversed without messing up the x axis.
As a bonus, I have been trying to come up with a way to have the size of the dots scale with the size of the graph so that they don't overlap when you shrink the plot size:
[image: Figure 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reverse is due to how the cartesian plane is implemented. To avoid this, use the reversed `ylim = c(8.5, 0.5)` instead:

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x=Column, y=Row)) +
  geom_point(data=expand.grid(seq(1, 12), seq(1,8)), 
             aes(x=Var1, y=Var2),
             color="grey90", 
             fill="white", 
             shape=21, 
             size=12) +
  coord_fixed(ratio=(13/12)/(9/8), 
              xlim=c(0.5, 12.5), 
              ylim=c(8.5, 0.5)) +  
  scale_y_reverse(breaks=seq(1, 8),
                  labels=LETTERS[1:8]) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 12))
```

[image]